# Why can't I add information to Firebase db?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to connect my web app to my Firebase database but it will not add the information to it. I would like the user to enter information into the system and this information be stored into the database entitled "appts":

JS function:

```
var config = {
apiKey: "____________",
authDomain: "southern-motors.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://southern-motors.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "southern-motors",
storageBucket: "southern-motors.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "852338882104"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('appts');

document.getElementById('appts').addEventListener('submit', addAppt);
function addAppt(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
var inputName = document.getElementById("customerName").value;
var inputEmail = 
document.getElementById("customerEmail").value.toLowerCase();
var inputPhone = document.getElementById("customerPhone").value;
var inputDate = document.getElementById("customerDate").value;

messagesRef.push({
                name: inputName,
                email: inputEmail,
                phone: inputPhone,
                date: inputDate
            }).then(function() {
console.log("Document successfully written!");
location.reload();
})
.catch(function(error) {
console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});

}
```

Input Form:

```
<div class="contact-form">
         <form id="appts" 
action="https://formspree.io/MYEMAIL" method="POST">
        <label>Name: </label><input id="customerName" class ="form-control" 
type="text" name="Name of Customer" required></input>

        </br>
        <label>Email Address: </label><input id="customerEmail" class="form- 
control" type="email" name="Email Address" required></input>
        </br>

        <label>Phone no.: </label><input id="customerPhone" class ="form- 
control" type="number" name="Phone No." required></input>
        </br>
        <label>Date & Time of Test Drive: </label><input id="customerDate" 
class ="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="Date & Time of Test Drive" 
required></input>
        </br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

A similar "register user" function works on a different form so I'm not sure why this isn't working. All suggestions welcome.

Comment: Any specific security rule that could prevent the write?

Comment: Do you see in the log the output of `console.log("Document successfully written!");`? Or you see the output of the `catch()`.

Comment: How do you check that the data is added to the database? Through the Firebase console? If yes, where do you exactly look in the console?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it worked as provided.  This means the problem is with permissions.

Check your console after pressing submit and you'll most likely see this error:

```
Error writing document:  Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
    at firebase.js:1
    at Dr (firebase.js:1)
    at t.callOnCompleteCallback (firebase.js:1)
    at firebase.js:1
    at firebase.js:1
    at e.onDataMessage_ (firebase.js:1)
    at t.onDataMessage_ (firebase.js:1)
    at t.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (firebase.js:1)
    at t.onMessage (firebase.js:1)
    at t.appendFrame_ (firebase.js:1)
(anonymous) @ test.html:65
Promise.catch (async)
addAppt @ test.html:64
```

This error means you don't have access.  Visit [Firebase's security page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) to learn more about security rules.

If you want to open the database to everyone, use the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```